# Reading images from directory in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am facing the problem in reading images from multiple directory in python. Like there is single image in png format and it is located in multiple folders. I want to keep a for loop on that and then access the image like from every folder. So what could be the way to read those images from the particular folder?

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import glob

%matplotlib inline
mypath='E:/Datasets/CBIS-DDSM PNG/Converted_Test'

onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
images = np.empty(len(onlyfiles), dtype=object)    
for n in range(0, len(onlyfiles)):    
    images[n] = cv2.imread( join(mypath,onlyfiles[n]) )
```

Comment: You might want to consider using `os.glob`

Comment: What's the problem with the approach you've provided?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try another method to reach to the directories for reading images.
in  **`imread()`** you can pass the directory .so you can use `str()`  and `+` to combine dynamic directories and fixed directory.
Here is the example maybe help you :

```
path = '/home/pictures/1'
for i in range(2) :
    image = cv2.imread(str(path)+'1'+'/222.jpg')
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
```

In this example I had 2 folder `11` and `12` so with a for loop I changed folders that I need.